# Annoying scroll icon next to cursor after installing drivers for mouse

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse

I just bought a new mouse and after installing the drivers, this annoying thing  appears and I don't know how to disable it! Or maybe I don't know what that is (Appears on pages where I can scroll the page only). I also can't scroll wherever this thing appears.

[image]

My mouse is "Sharkoon Fireglider Optical" and this is the menu that lets me customize things

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I just found how to fix it:

- Go to:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\GamingMouseEditor\GamingMouseEditor\ini
  ```
- Open `Main.ini`
- Search for `[W4D]` and below this (the one without `//` before) replace:

  ```
  Disable=0
  ```

  with:

  ```
  Disable=1
  ```

  like this:

  [image: like this]
- Restart Gaming mouse editor, or restart you computer, it should by fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Scroll icon next to cursor

This indicates your mouse wheel is in "small" scroll mode:

- The mouse wheel will scroll the page by a smaller amount when it is in this mode.
- The scroll icon will appear when you click the mouse wheel.
- Turn "small" scroll mode off by clicking the scroll wheel again.

Comment: When I click it it disappears for a sec but then re-appears. The scroll wheel won't work when this icon appears, but after testing it seems that it isn't broken.

Comment: @PanV I'm confused, because my Logitech trackerball mouse scroll wheel works just like I described. You may have to adjust the double click settings of your "middle mouse button" - which is the scroll wheel

Comment: But I don't have double click settings on it

Comment: Then I don't know. My double click settings can be changed in start > control panel > mouse > buttons ...

Comment: Ι just found out that after clicking the scroll wheel the "Small" Scroll Mode disappears, but after a second it reappears. During Small Scroll Mode my mouse won't scroll. When Chrome isn't a "focused window", the small scroll mode disappears and I can scroll. The point is, how am I supposed to remove it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution (like I was):

1. Right-click on the Mouse Editor symbol in your taskbar (bottom right corner)
2. Choose "4D Wheel"
3. Disable 4D Wheel by setting it to "Normal Wheel"

Comment: Your answer is the same as another one